# How to write an expression for the following [Pop In object]?

Tags: after-effects, adobe, after-effects-expressions, after-effects-scripting

**[Pop In](https://youtu.be/ZvQo4ryiyFQ?t=18) object (@ 17s)**

I'm fairly new to Expressions, I'm trying to attain this effect with expressions. I tried using the inertial bounce code on the net

```
n = 0;
if (numKeys > 0){
n = nearestKey(time).index;
if (key(n).time > time){
n--;
}
}
if (n == 0){
t = 0;
}else{
t = time - key(n).time;
}

if (n > 0 && t < 1){
v = velocityAtTime(key(n).time - thisComp.frameDuration/10);
amp = .05;
freq = 4.0;
decay = 8.0;
value + v*amp*Math.sin(freq*t*2*Math.PI)/Math.exp(decay*t);
}else{
value;
}
```

To make this generic, I acquired the desired result by creating a null object with a scale value of `100`, applied the above code to the null and added `s=linear(thisComp.layer("Null 8").transform.scale[0],0,150, 0,desiredScale); [s,s]` to the required object's scale. Though this works decently, this is such a pain to do for every object (I have a lot of objects for which I want to apply this effect). Is there a simpler way?